# "В общем-то"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли брать в запятые оборот "в общем-то" в предложениях такого рода: "Он(,) в общем-то(,) совсем неплохой"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно. Это вводное слово, синонимичное "вообще говоря".